# Azure web app configuration

Tags: azure-devops, azure-webjobs

I have been using azure PowerShell tasks to update my app settings in the portal for all the web apps and would like to know if there is any other way to do the same.

I don't want to make the changes in the config files alone. The changes have to be made in the azure portal as well.

Comment: Can you provide an example of what configuration item(s) you are updating, an example script using powershell, etc.?

Comment: @raterus I have been using the PowerShell task to update values like the connection strings and the app settings . Like configuring the existing key value pairs or adding new pairs

Comment: Are you deploying a .net application?  All of that can be handled through app.config/web.config, and you can link those keys to VSTS variables and avoid all the powershell scripting.

Comment: Basically I am looking for an option to update appsettings in azure portal without using PowerShell,  we have a number of projects in different languages ( .Net, Java etc). We are not using the web.config to update the settings in portal.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few third-party tools to accomplish this and avoid Powershell.  Basically it takes your VSTS variables, and sets them in Azure.  You install these as release tasks.

[Azure WebApp Configuration task](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=pascalnaber.PascalNaber-Xpirit-WebAppConfiguration)

[Azure App Service: Set App settings](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=pascalnaber.PascalNaber-Xpirit-WebAppConfiguration)

Answer (score 0):

In current Azure stack you have two options.

1. For secured settings you should rather use "Azure Key Vault"
2. For Centralized app settings you should use "Azure App Configuration" which is in public preview.